# What is the name of this digraph created from other digraphs?

Tags: graph-theory, notation, directed-graphs

Let $D_1, D_2, ..., D_n$ be digraphs of various sizes and let $C$ be a diagraph with $n$ vertices $\{1,...,n\}$. Construct a new digraph, $D$, whose vertex set is $V(D) = V(D_1) \cup \cdots \cup V(D_n)$ and whose edge set is defined by $u \to v$ if and only if one of the two conditions hold:

$\quad$(a) $u,v \in V(D_i) \text{ and } u \to v \text{ in } D_i$

$\quad$(b) $\exists i \neq j$ such that $u \in V(D_i), v\in V(D_j)\text{ and } i \to j \text{ in } C$.

In other words, $D$ is the digraph obtained by replacing the vertices of $C$ with the diagraphs $D_1,D_2,...,D_n$.

**Question:** Is there a canonical name/notation for this process? I was digging through the Wikipedia article [Graph operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_operations) to find something similar, but to no avail (perhaps I just missed it). In particular, I'm interested in when $D_1, D_2, ..., D_n$ are strongly connected and $C$ is transitive. Then the condensation of $D$ is $C$. My idea is to "reverse" the process of condensation.

Comment: Is $V(D)$ meant to be a disjoint union of the sets $V(D_i),$ which may not be disjoint?

Comment: @CalumGilhooley Since the vertices come from different diagraphs, it is implicitly assumed that $V(D_1), ..., V(D_n)$ are pairwise disjoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a canonical name for this process in this article: [Hamiltonian tournaments with the least number of $3$-cycles](https://doi.org/10.1002/jgt.3190140606). The author calls $D = C(D_1,D_2,...,D_n)$ the *composition* of the $n$ *components* $M_1,M_2,...,M_n$ with the *quotient* $C$.

Answer (score 4):

This can be phrased as a "partial graph join" (the graph join is a well-known operation) described by $C$. Indeed, suppose $C$ has the edge $1 \to 2$. Then $D$ has an edge $u \to v$ if $u \in D_1$ and $v \in D_2$; i.e., join all vertices of $D_1$ to vertices of $D_2$, respecting the orientation $1 \to 2$.

Thus the adjacency matrix $A$ of $D$ will be of the following block form, writing $IJ$ for the $ij$th block of the adjacency matrix, $A_i$ for the adjacency matrix of $D_i$, $\mathbf{1}$ for the all-ones matrix, and $\mathbf{0}$ for the all-zeroes matrix:

$$(A)_{IJ} = \begin{cases} A_i &\text{if } I = J = i \\ \mathbf{1} &\text{if } I \to J \in C\\ \mathbf{0} &\text{else }\end{cases}$$

Based off a comment, if we denote the graph join as $G \leftrightarrow H$, then one can extend this by induction to $\leftrightarrow_{j=1}^n G_j$, which is clearly associative. Then if we index the graph created by the procedure in the question as $C(D_1,\dots,D_n)$ one can see why I thought "partial" graph join was a suitable name; on the underlying graphs $G_i$ of the $D_i$:

$$K_n(G_1,\dots G_n) = \hphantom{ }\leftrightarrow_{j=1}^n G_j$$

It is also partial in the sense that this algorithm acts on digraphs, which could be considered "partial graphs" insofar as we can identify (nonloop) $2$-cycles with edges.

Comment: What do you mean by "partial" in "partial graph join"? Do you mean that the process I described is like a graph join but is slightly different? As I understand it, graph join is a binary operation and hence doesn't quite work for $n$ (or is it $n+1$?) inputs.

Comment: The graph join is indeed a binary operation, but this "partial" graph join is a specified subgraph of an iterated $n$-fold graph join.

Comment: To clarify, by the notation $G \leftrightarrow H$, do you mean that every vertex in $G$ beats every vertex in $H$ and vice versa?

Comment: What do you mean by "beat"? The notation was chosen because the graph join produces a new graph with new edges between every pair of vertices $u \in G$ and $v \in H$.

Comment: By $u$ beats $v$, I mean $u \to v$.

Comment: Then I essentially do mean this. The operation of the graph join is defined on undirected graphs, so I really refer to a new edge $uv$ for every $u \in G$ and $v \in H$. However, edges $uv$ can be identified as $u$ and $v$ beating each other when we pass to an orientation on the underlying undirected graph.